# SQL command in ecel VBA gives db server error - MariaDB

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, mariadb

I have problem with part of excel VBA macro that should load data from csv file, to MariaDB tables. SQL command, which works in HeidiSQL, return error when used in VBA. The error message is:

[ma-3.0.3][10.2.13-MariaDB]This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet.

Here is the VBA code.

```
DBConn = "DSN=Fundusze;UID=login;PWD=pass;"    

Command = "Load data low_priority local infile '" + Replace(Plik, "\", "/") + "' replace into table _kurs_" + ID + " fields terminated by ';' lines terminated by '\r\n' ignore 0 lines (`Data`, `Notowanie`);"
Call ZapisDB(Command, DBConn)

Sub ZapisDB(SQL_Com As String, Connection As String)
Dim DBConn As ADODB.Connection

Set DBConn = New ADODB.Connection
DBConn.ConnectionString = Connection
DBConn.Open

DBConn.Execute (SQL_Com)
DBConn.Close
Set DBConn = Nothing

End Sub
```

I am aware that this is rather db server side problem, but what can I do if I need to load lot of data into lot od tables ? Why SQL command which is fine and works in HeidiSQL cannot be send via ODBC ?

**EDIT - problem solved by making workaround**

I have made a workaround to not use 'load data infile' as it seems that it is not supported by DB engine accessed via ODBC. I'm using 'insert into' query preparing string of values from csv which should be inserted.

Comment: which line is giving you the error?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thought that it's clear. DBConn.Execute (SQL_Com) gives error, but it is dbengine error. I just don't know why SQL command which is correct, cannot be executed via VBA and ODBC.

Comment: Why do you assume that the SQL query is correct? I'm not convinced that it is.  Have you tested it directly since you started getting this error? What is the SQL query?  Is it supposed to be in `SQL_Com`?

Comment: Did you read my first post ? I have written that the SQL command is already tested and working using HeidiSQL graphic interface. Same command send via ODBC in VBA returns DB Engine error. Query is in source code I have provided - 2nd line of code and it then provided to Sub ZapisDB, which I have written. Yes it is supposed to be in SQL_Com and it is there, when I debug it.

Comment: Alright, don't bother taking my advice, good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

I might be going out on a limb here and bet that you will find the problem(s) by adding this line at the very top of this module:

```
Option Explicit
```

(and in the future, always adding that to every module.)

This "forces" you to properly declare and refer to variables, objects, properties, etc.

Comment: I have it on all of my modules. Problem is not in VBA itself.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it's better to use ExecuteNonQuery() as it's for Insert/Delete/Update :

```
 Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("DataSource=dev;Database=mydb;User ID=myUser;Password=mypass;")
    Try
        con.Open()
        Dim sql As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Command, con)
        sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        con.Close()
        MsgBox("Record is not Inserted" + ex.Message)
    End Try
```

One other thing you need to verify are the `/` you may have to transform in `\`

Comment: Hmm yes, I forgot to write that this is excel VBA (already edited). So your proposal will not work, unfortunately. Actually I'm currently working on workaround, as it seems that DBEngine just don't support those command (load data infile) via DBConnector (ODBC). Or meybe I am missing something ?

Comment: Ok I have made a workaround which works fine, for thing I want to achievie. I just use insert SQL query, preparing string of values from csv file file.